# Implementing onClickListener on ImageView inside a layout inflated by adapter to change its drawablesrc

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter

My app has a layout looking like this
[LAyout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz9oE.png)

And this is inflated by a adapter, creating a listview containing many such layouts with the contents of the layout changing according to the position.
Everything is ok upto this.

Now I need to set a onClickListener on the playButton and it will play a very short music and its imagesrc will change from play image to pause image.

I implemented the the playing of music in the adapter itself by setting an onClickListeners on each of playButton in the layouts I inflated. in getView(). (is this the best way to do this?)

Now that also worked perfectly untill I tried changing the imagesrc when the playButtton will be Clicked.

What happens is the last layout that is inflated by the adapter only its imagesrc changes on clicking. That is no matter which layout's playButton I click on, the correct music plays, but the imagesrc is changed of the playButton in the last layout inflated last by the adapter.
Why is this happening?

Here is the code of my adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyCustomObject> {


private static AudioManager mAudioManager;

private static MediaPlayer mMedia;

private ImageView mPlayButton;

private Context mContext;

/**
 * A custom created Constructor
 * this is used to inflate a custom created layout file
 */
public MyAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<MyCustomObject> wordArrayList) {

    super(context, 0, wordArrayList);
    this.mContext = context;

}

private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

        mPlayButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_action_play));
        releaseMediaPlayer();
    }
};

public static AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener mOnAudioFocusChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {

        if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT ||
                focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) {

            mMedia.pause();
            mMedia.seekTo(0);

        } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {

            mMedia.start();
        } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
            releaseMediaPlayer();
        }

    }
};

public static void releaseMediaPlayer() {

    if (mMedia != null) {

        mMedia.release();
        mMedia = null;
        mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener);
    }
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    View currentView = convertView;

    if (currentView == null)
        currentView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_to_be_inflated, parent, false);

    final MyCustomObject currentObject = getItem(position);


    /**Setting the {@id englishID} of the miwokenglishlist.xml
     * to the the desired english value
     */

    //Getting the ID
    TextView defalutTextView = (TextView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.englishID);

    //Changing the text of the view
    defalutTextView.setText(currentWordObject.getEnglishWord());

    /**
     * Setting the {@id miwokID} of the miwokenglishlist.xml
     * to the current miwok word
     */

    // Getting the ID
    TextView secondaryTextView = (TextView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.secondID);

    // Changing the text to the current miwok word
    miwokTextView.setText(currentObject.getSecondWord());

    /**
     * Checking whether current Word object has a image associated with it or not
     */
    // Getting the image id from the current word object
    int currImageID = currentObject.getImageResourceID();

    // Getting the ID for the image in miwokenglishlist.xml
    ImageView imageViewID = (ImageView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.imageID);

    // if image is present for the current object
    if (currImageID != -1) {

        // Setting the image on the layout
        imageViewID.setImageResource(currImageID);
    }

    // if image is not present for the current object
    else {

        imageViewID.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    mPlayButton = (ImageView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

    mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // If there are already underlying resources
            releaseMediaPlayer();

            int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);

            if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {

                mMedia = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), currentWordObject.getPronunciation());
                mMedia.start();
                mMedia.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
`//Changing the playButton resource to pause`   
                     mPlayButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,
                                    R.drawable.ic_action_pause));
                    }
                });

                mMedia.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
            }
        }
    });

    // Returning the modified inflated View
    return currentView;
}
}
```

So how do i do this?

**UPDATE:** I solved the issue, i was calling setDrawablesrc on the mPlayButton id which referred to the playButton in the last layout which was inflated. So, I called the setDrawablesrc on the view that was passed in the onClick method of the onClickListener.
Here is the updated code

```
mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {

            // If there are already underlying resources
            releaseMediaPlayer();

            int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);

            if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
//Storing the view in the instance variable to refer to it in the onCompletionlIstener of the MediaPlayer
                mPlayButtonView = (ImageView) view;

                mMedia = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), currentWordObject.getPronunciation());
                mMedia.start();
                mMedia.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

//Changing the imagesrc of the view that is passed

((ImageView)view).setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,
                                    R.drawable.ic_action_pause));
                    }
                });

                mMedia.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
            }
        }
    });
```

And in the onCompletionListener i took the instance variable and changed its imagesrc.
Worked perfectly! :)

**Now one question lies, is this the best way to do this?**

Comment: *yes*. Basically, a lot but it would be impossible to explain via StackOverflow. I'll just give you one initial tip: _I implemented the the playing of music in the adapter itself_ -> This alone is a little bit atrocious. Not only an adapter should know nothing about Media Playback at all, but also, it is very inefficient. From there, you can start thinking about a better solution. Remember the basics: Single Responsibility Principle… Inversion of Control, etc. All these things are annoying but are here to help :)

Comment: I agree, need to think about a better solution @MartinMarconcini